# ssh-agent: don't forward authentication for the whole keyring

Tags: ssh, security, ssh-agent

I have two private ssh keys :

- one to access my *personnal* machines,
- one to access servers at my *job*.

I add those two keys to my ssh-agent with `ssh-add`.

Now, when I do `ssh -A root@jobsrv` I would like to forward agent authentication only for my job key (the one I'm using to connect `jobsrv`).

I want this because anyone having root access to `jobsrv` can use my agent to authenticate himself to my personnal machines.

Is there a way to achieve this isolation?

Comment: did you check the -i option in man page of ssh?

Comment: @Stillakid yes, `ssh -A -i myjobkey_rsa root@jobsrv` still allows the jobsrv machine to access my local machine agent and authenticate on my personnal server with the other (personnal) key...

Comment: also checked ssh-keysign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, **I believe it is not possible to achive this *easily* at the present moment**. One could use two agents (one for each key) so that there is no agent holding every keys. But this would be pretty cumbersome to work with.

This is why a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2093) (enhancement) has been opened. There is [this similar report](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1499) too.

Answer (score 2):

In order to force `ssh(1)` to use a particular key even if `ssh-agent(1)` offers multiple ones, use the `IdentityFile` and `IdentitiesOnly` directive in `~/.ssh/config`, e.g.:

```
Host example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/special.pem
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

See `ssh_config(5)` for details.

Comment: **This does not work**. `IdentitiesOnly` applies when you try to connect to the remote server. Once you're connected, if `-A` agent forwarding is enabled, the whole keyring is forwarded.

Comment: The keyring is not forwarded out. It is the auth request that is forwarded *in*.

Comment: @bahamat Sure, my mistake. Still, this solution does not work.