# Does ssh-add honor the declarations made in ssh_config file(s)?

Tags: ssh, openssh, key-authentication, ssh-agent, ssh-config

### Background

I use a 4096-bit RSA key-pair for authorizing access to my server. By `ssh_config` files I am referring to `~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Here's what my `~/.ssh/config` looks like:

```
Host gg-root
    HostName 172.47.95.122

Host ss-root
    HostName 172.47.95.123

# Common for my servers
Host gg-root ss-root
    User root
    Port 32001
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bull

# Common for all
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Now, I can simply connect to my server via SSH with the following (without any further configuration):

```
ssh gg-root
ssh ss-root
```

Thing is, I need to add the private key `~/.ssh/id_rsa_bull` to the system's SSH agent to make it easily available to other apps like FileZilla which I use for SFTP. (Esp. because I don't like that FileZilla needs an unencrypted private key as `.ppk`.)

So, I either run this command each time:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pepper
```

Or have this in my `~/.profile`:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pepper > /dev/null 2>&1
```

### Question

When I add the key to the system's SSH agent using `ssh-add`, does it honor  the declarations I've made in `ssh_config` file(s)? Specifically, does it make sure that `~/.ssh/id_rsa_pepper` is only used for `172.47.95.{122,123}`?

Based on how I interpreted what I read, I believe it should. If I am wrong, please enlighten me as to how I should go about adding a private key to the system's SSH agent where the said private key is only used for stated hosts?

---

### EDIT: Based on Answer

This is what my `~/.ssh/config` looks like now:

```
Host gg-root
    HostName 172.47.95.122

Host ss-root
    HostName 172.47.95.123

# Common for my servers
Host gg-root ss-root
    User root
    Port 32001
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bull

# Common for all
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: I must be missing something.  Why would it matter if it tries to use that key on other servers?  It won’t work, so it will go on to the next key, right?

Comment: @Wildcard So as not to trigger fail2ban & other security mechanisms (because they are considered login attempts). Also because that's not optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh-add` does not honour the configuration file.  It just adds the key to the agent.

The `ssh` client would try to use the key `~/.ssh/id_rsa_bull` when connecting to either of `gg-root` or `ss-root` (due to the `IdentityFile` configuration).  If that key is available in the agent, then it will be used from there, otherwise the key will be used from file (and a password may have to be provided if the key has one associated with it).

The keys in the agent would also be used when connecting to *any other host* not configured with a specific `IdentityFile` in `~/.ssh/config`.  This means that the configuration restricts the keys used for authenticating with particular hosts, but the shown configuration does not stop the "bull key" from being used with other hosts.

Comment: So, that means it would be a good idea to add `IdentitiesOnly yes` under `Host *` so that key files aren't used unless `IdentityFile` is specifically declared. That means, in other cases, SSH/SSH agent will look for normal password authentication. Am I getting this right?

Comment: @its_me Ah, yes, that is correct.  And that should probably go last in the the configuration file.

Comment: Just came across this, and it seems to negate my understanding? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72677/9610

Comment: @its_me The user that wrote the accepted answer there does not seem to know about `IdentitiesOnly`.  The other answerer does. Note also that that question is regarding the identities that are provided through agent forwarding to the remote host (a slightly different question from yours).

Comment: Same as what you said, but note to self: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36363402